# Android - detect gesture on webview

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to detect the swipe gesture on the webview.

I try to use the function below:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
    String DEBUG_TAG = "test";

    switch (action) {
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was DOWN");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was MOVE");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was UP");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL):
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was CANCEL");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE):
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Movement occurred outside bounds " +
                    "of current screen element");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

When there is no webview, it works and get back the correct answer.
However, when I added the above, it doesn't work on the webview. As the webview must be in full screen, I think I cannot use the function above.
Is there any other method or I have something wrong?

Comment: who is the listener of the touch event you implemented?

Comment: Do I need to implement a listener? I just put the function in the Activity only.

Comment: try to implement a listener and pass it to the setOnTouchListener function in the webview